# Run matlab code on javascript

Tags: javascript, html, matlab

I have a simple matlab code. It loads a file and draws a graph using datas in this file. I want that when I press a html button, the graph is drew.I read some recommendations on web/blogs. Have to I use com server?

**EDIT**

My app is not a web app yet. I run it local pc, it is just a htm file.I use google chrome for now.

Comment: Your best bet is just porting it to JavaScript.

Comment: @PitaJ,when I search porting code, I find solution about convert code. Should I convert the code matlab to javascript?

Comment: When you press a html button on what browser (Matlab or other) ? Is Matlab installed on your server ? Please give some details, we cannot read in you mind.

Comment: From the title of your question, I would say yes.

Comment: I don't have a server yet. It works my local. It is just a htm file. I use google chrome for now.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is not necessary, you could have some workarounds to avoid using a COM server (although it's well explained in the official [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-functions-from-a-web-application.html)).

It depends if your webapp is a Java application, PHP, etc.

A simple approach using PHP would be using [passthru](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) to run your matlab app and later you could link to the generated file.

Related questions:

- [Can I run MATLAB code on a web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451503/can-i-run-matlab-code-on-a-web-site)
- [How to run MATLAB code from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130539/how-to-run-matlab-codes-from-java-end)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do so would be for you to generate the C++ code out of Matlab code using [Matlab coder](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder.html), then there are a few way ways to run C/C++ codes in the browser, see below links:

[Running C in A Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713194/running-c-in-a-browser) and [Native client](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client)

It is worthwhile to mention that it might not be the best idea and you might face many fundamental issues since you are practically converting Matlab code two times to different programming languages. Currently, there are many issues with Google Native Client, including the fact that you can not run it on every browser, other services are essentially better than the google native client.

Finally, if you have a simple code I would recommend you to rewrite it in JS instead of going throw all the trouble.