# Best way to build an application based on R?

Tags: python, user-interface, r

I'm looking for suggestions on how to go about building an application that uses `R` for analytics, table generation, and plotting. What I have in mind is an application that:

- displays various data tables in different tabs, somewhat like in Excel, and the columns should be sortable by clicking.
- takes user input parameters in some dialog windows.
- displays plots dynamically (i.e. user-input-dependent) either in a tab or in a new pop-up window/frame

Note that I am *not* talking about a general-purpose fron-end/GUI for exploring data with `R` (like say `Rattle`), but a specific application.
Some questions I'd like to see addressed are:

- Is an entirely R-based approach even possible ( on Windows ) ? The following passage from the `Rattle` article in `R`-Journal intrigues me:

> It is interesting to note that the
>   first implementation of Rattle
>   actually used Python for implementing
>   the callbacks and R for the
>   statistics, using `rpy`. The release
>   of `RGtk2` allowed the interface el-
>   ements of `Rattle` to be written
>   directly in R so that `Rattle` is a
>   **fully R-based application**

- If it's better to use another language for the GUI part, which language is best suited for this? I'm looking for a language where it's relatively "painless" to build the GUI, and that also integrates very well with `R`. From this StackOverflow question [How should I do rapid GUI development for R and Octave methods (possibly with Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691944/how-should-i-do-rapid-gui-development-for-r-and-octave-methods-possibly-with-pyt) I see that `Python` + `PyQt4` + `QtDesigner` + `RPy2` seems to be the best combo. Is that the consensus ?
- Anyone have pointers to specific (open source) applications of the type I describe, as examples that I can learn from?

Comment: If you've never build a GUI before then I'm not sure you'll achieve success without at least a modicum of pain!

Comment: Sure I'm willing to go through some pain :)

Comment: One thing I'd want to evaluate carefully was the performance of the grid/table display widget with the clickable headers. These can be of very variable quality.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, including the python approach you mention. If you want to do it solely within R and if your aims are modest enough, the gWidgets package can be used. This exposes some of the features of either RGtk2, tcltk or qtbase (see the qtinterfaces project on r-forge) in a manner that is about as painless as can be. If you want more, look at using those packages directly. I'd recommend RGtk2 if you are going to share with others and if not, qtbase or tcltk.

Comment: +1 --  John has done wonderful work with these `gWidgets` wrappers.

Comment: thanks @jverzani (and nice to hear from the author of one of the very first R intro documents I read 10 yrs ago!). I'll check out the `gWidgets` and related packages. I'm also looking for a way to get things to work on a Mac (Snow Leopard) and I keep getting error messages when I try to click on one of the demo dialogs of RGtk2. This is apparently a common problem... I have to keep digging.

Comment: @jverzani your last point doesn't make sense, the bit where you suggest that RGtk2 is more portable than RGtk2. Must be a typo.

Comment: +1 Michael Lawrence and DTL have just had a paper on RGtk2 in JSS: http://www.jstatsoft.org/v37/i08 which @Prasad might want to look at for ideas/info.

Comment: Ok I took a quick look at the JSS paper and it looks like  RGtk2 and gWidgets are the most promising approaches for building apps that use R analytics, especially for people who have a strong preference for coding in R. I think these are very much worth spending time to learn.

Comment: +1 for being jverzani. I am seconding Chalasani's thanks for the documentation work you have done in the past. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Python + Qt4 + RPy = Much Win.

For example, see what Carson Farmer has done with Qgis and the ManageR plugin - its a full R interface to geographic data in the Qgis mapping package.

Depending on how much statistical functionality you need you might even get away without needing it at all, doing all the stats in Python, leveraging such goodies as the Numpy numeric package and the Qwt plotting canvas.

Comment: +1 Python and PyQt are wonderful, but perhaps not the easiest to learn. Once you have got the knack then it's great. Matplotlib is probably the most commonly used plotting package in the Python world.

Comment: Actually, the really insightful part of this answer is the recognition that, if the user doesn't need the interactive goodness of the general purpose R language, then using a Python numeric package like Numpy/Scipy would make for much easier coding.

Comment: I definitely want to be able to leverage sophisticated `R` packages and functionality, so I would not consider an approach where all my code is in Python with Python Numerical packages. But from what I've been reading, if you *have* to interface to `R` from another language, then the best language to do this from is `Python` (is that true?), and I really don't mind learning Python if only for the GUI part (Python seems like an interesting language).

Comment: @Prasad there are some pretty sophisticated packages for Python too, but since you haven't said anything about the actual methods that you intend to use, it's hard to know whether or not you really do need R.

Comment: @David I actually don't have a specific application in mind, I'm just exploring what's possible, without having to give up on all the experience I've gained with `R`, and all the useful packages that have been built for `R`. For example, I would want to be able to use `ggplot2` to easily produce nice looking plots from `R`.

Comment: @Prasad You can make nice plots with Python too. I guess you just need to weigh up all the pros and cons.

Comment: @David let's just say I have an `R` bias, and leave it at that :)

Comment: @Prasad the R-plotting commands can be easily invoked from rpy2 as well. Here is how http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-dev/html/graphics.html

Comment: @whatnick that does look nice, thanks. I am wondering though if I really need Python to build the GUI? The R packages gWidgets and RGtk2 seem to be fairly easy to use. Is there an advantage to using Python for the GUI?

Comment: @Prasad Nothing except more choice, Python gives you options like Qt, wxWidgets and GTK is there too.

Comment: If you go the python and R route with Rpy2 - if a user were to use your GUI application - won't they also need R on the machine? My limited understanding is Rpy2 and solutions which use R servers or communication with an R process is R needs to be on the machine, whereas my impression of C++ and RInside is it actually embeds the R engine in the application - is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

How about traditional LAMP + a R backend? Optionally s/MySQL/Postgres and optionally s/PHP/Perl Rapache looks pretty cool too: [rapache.net](http://www.rapache.net)

Comment: I would not have thought that Apache, MySQL and PHP would be strictly necessary!

Comment: @OneWhoIsUnnamed Did you just swallow a buzzword catalogue?! What has any of this got to do with the OP's question?  -1

Comment: Apache and Jeff's RApache (R inside Apache) and gWidgetsWWW by John are indeed a nice combination too.

Comment: @David Hefernan: PHP/RApache allows you to create a web-based application that uses R as a back-end for graphs/stats. So... no buzzword catalogue, it's a perfectly valid solution. The only "problem" is that you need your own server, as I do not know of any shared hosts that provide RApache.

Answer (score 1):

If you go for C++, take a look at [rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html) and [Rinside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html)

Java can be combined with R using [JRI](http://www.rforge.net/JRI/)

[RServe](http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/) gives you a TCP/IP protocol to interact with R. There's a Java client and a C++ client, so either of them can be used.

On a sidenote: Another thing you should be aware of, is that R contains quite some libraries written in Fortran and C, that can be called directly. Same goes for more advanced packages like VGAM, they also contain quite some C routines. Depending on what exactly you want to do, you might try to work with those ones, just to avoid the overhead of the R functions itself.

I've been looking for an overview of those myself, but AFAIK you'll have to do some effort to get everything. Some things you certainly should look at is The [R language definition](http://www.studiegids.ugent.be/2010/NL/FACULTY/C/MAMA/CNSDAN/CNSDAN.html) and [R Internals](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.pdf).

Comment: just clarifying -- are you saying there are many *GUI* libraries for R written in c/c++, and so I could just use them " natively" from R? Which packages are those? Note that my main requirement is to have a friendly GUI front-end that command-line-fearing people can interact with.

Comment: @Prasad: No, I mean you can use the internal C and Fortran libraries from R also in other languages. So depending what you're doing, an interface between C and the language of your choice can be sufficient. If you have heavy calculations the loss of all R overhead can increase performance substantially. But that doesn't work for the plotting off course, and you really have to know what you're doing. I've been dabbling around in the source code to figure out some of those.

Comment: ok I see what you mean -- if I have my main application code (GUI, etc) written in C++, then I could just #include Rcpp and invoke the R internals directly from my C++ code. It is probably is a great approach from a performance point of view. But it is definitely more difficult to write the entire App in C++, but I would not go in that direction-- I'm not that brave :)

Comment: @Prasad: Not exactly. Rcpp builds an interface between R and C++ to move your data objects between them. It is mainly used to call C++ code from within R. Rinside (sorry, forgot to mention it) allows you to use your R-code from within C++. The C and fortran libraries can be called using the appropriate mechanisms in the language of your choice. I just mentioned it to point out both C++ and Java can relatively easy be linked with R. But if you prefer Python, by all means, use it. If you ever think of going the C++ way, be sure to look for the work of @Dirk Eddelbuettel.