# R computation at server side

Tags: java, web-services, r, server-side

I am trying to develop a web application, which allows users to input data through Web, and select according data analysis procedures. I will have a R program running at the server side. It conducts related analysis based on the input and requested procedures.

I only have R programming skills but I never did any Web applications. I would like to know which necessary skills are required for this kind of project, and how to enable R to do server-side computations. I really appreciate your response.

Comment: Perhaps not an exact duplicate, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397097/r-web-application-introduction) covers some similar ground.

Comment: You should head over to http://www.w3schools.com/ and cover some basic stuff: HTML, CSS, PHP, JavaScript, AJAX, jQuery, (My)SQL. Good luck! =)

Answer (score 3):

Your options are quite wide this time:

- [RApache](http://rapache.net/): ideal solution if you happen to know Apache webserver and might have some slight knowledge of PHP. Without any decent chance for statefull implementation! Well, this stands true for most later suggestions also :)
- check also [Rook](https://github.com/jeffreyhorner/rRack), which is a really inspiring and promising initiative,
- [proprietary web engine of Revolution Analytics](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/products/enterprise-deployment.php): if you would go the Java way, especially with the [JasperReports extension](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/partners/jaspersoft/),
- call R-script from any programming language: if you prefer this, do check [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html)!,
- use of [Rserve](http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/): many clients implemented/being implemented. Sessions are also handled in some way.

**But anyway:** you should have a deep knowledge of HTML, CSS and JavaScript despite the fact which way you choose. And also, do not forget about managing the (web/database/etc.) server :)

Comment: Note that RevoDeployR is a full-blown framework for R-powered web applications, built upon Rserve. And, no, it's not free (as in free beer nor as in freedom).

Answer (score -1):

If I am not mistaken, R designed according to client - server philosophy. You don't have to do mach to make it Web enabled. Have a look at [R Installation and Administration](http://www.r-project.org/) and [R Web interface](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#R-Web-Interfaces). The only problem I see that UNIX-like and Windows installation are quite different.