# Useful packages to create online prediction tool with Python and R (example provided)

Tags: python, r, statistics, tkinter, rpy2

I am building a Cox PH statistical model to predict the probability of relapse for breast cancer patients.  I would like to create an online interface for patients or doctors to use that would allow them to input the relevant patient characteristics, and compute the probability of relapse.  Here is a perfect example, albeit for prostate cancer: 
http://nomograms.mskcc.org/Prostate/PostRadicalProstatectomy.aspx

My basic plan is to create the tool with python, and compute the probability with R based on the user's inputs and from my previously fitted Cox PH model.  The tool would require both drop-down boxes and user-inputted numerical values.  The problem is I've never done any web programming or GUI programming with Python.  My experience is with the scientific programming side of Python (e.g. Pylab, etc).  My questions are:

1. What relevant packages for Python and R will I need?  From some Googling I've done it seems that RPy and Tkinter are clear choices.
2. How can I store the statistical model such that the tool doesn't have to compute the model from my data set every time someone uses it?  In the case of a Cox PH model, this would require storing the baseline hazard and the model formula.
3. Any useful tips from your experience?

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Tkinter is a desktop GUI toolkit and won't be useful to create an online interface.

Comment: re: your point (2). Your 'perfect example' doesn't store anything - doesn't it just generate a new result from each input by the user? If you think you need to store something, then this is a bit more complex than the 'perfect example' you gave... So I think you need a step 0, to define your project more carefully from the users point of view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A web interface to an R program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294052/a-web-interface-to-an-r-program)

Comment: `DynNom` package may be of help

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to learn WebDev, which is a pretty massive topic. If you are serious about making this a webapp, Django is one of the easiest places to start, and it's also fantastically documented. So essentially my answer would be:

http://djangobook.com/en/2.0/

start reading.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using `R` through `RPy` or equivalent there are a number of survival analysis routines in the [statsmodels](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/statsmodels) (formerly `sicpy.statsmodel`) python library. They are in the "sandbox" package though, meaning they aren't supposed to be ready for production right now.

E.g. you have the Cox model of proportional hazard coded [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/sandbox/cox.py).

See also [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1736/survival-analysis-tools-in-python/62570#62570) on CrossValidated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest fitting your model in R and easily use the 'DynNom' package ('DNbuilder' function). It will create such an interactive tool for your prediction model that you can easily share it as a webpage without any web programming or GUI programming skills. This will be a line of code after fitting your model, for example:

```
fit1 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + ph.ecog, data = lung) 
library(DynNom)
DNbuilder(fit1)
```

You can easily share it on your account in http://shinyapps.io/ or host it on your website (needs more effort).